# The bird people in Beastmaster -- do we have any further information about them in other flicks or novelizations?

Tags: beastmaster

To me, these bird people who dissolve their prey were very unexpected and interesting -- I would say that without them, Beastmaster would have been 20% less good as a scifi/fantasy film. (Same thing with the men turned into monsters by the substance that destroys their minds.)

I call them bird people only because of their appearance but they really are not very bird like (iirc they do have wings) -- the acid thing is not very bird like, but it reminds me of the Goldblum version of The Fly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beast_Master - "*Ideas from the novel were featured in a 1982 film, The Beastmaster, which did not significantly follow the novel's plot.*"

Comment: does your comment imply that the novel does go into my beloved bird people or does it merely suggest that if i find the novel there might be discussion of them in it?

Comment: I've not read it. I was merely commenting that it was **a)** Based on a book (and hence it would be worth glancing through to see if there are any bird-men and **b)** That if bird-men exist in the book, they may be nothing like the ones in the film

Comment: well, i take my hat off to the person whoever it was that thought of the acid thing. what a frightening idea that i had not expected to see. the movie had an unusual feel due to such details and did not deserve the ridicule. The comic Doug Ferrari had this joke "HBO stands for How many times can Beastmaster be On" (I guess HBO did show the same B-movies over and over at one time.)

Comment: To be clear, you're  talking only about the film, not the TV series?

Comment: @releseabe I thought the canonical example was _Clash of the Titans_....

Comment: @Spencer: I was thinking of the movie, never saw TV series -- acidic bird people make further appearances in TV series? or other interesting species? what happens in clash of titans that is related to beastmaster and/or bird people?

Comment: @releseabe Clash of the Titans wasn't related to Beastmaster, except that it was infamous for being endlessly played on HBO.

Comment: @Spencer: okay, we were talking about many things and what you said was profoundly unclear. I guess HBO used to get the dregs; nowadays with netflix, hbo and others producing their own content things are improved. years ago there was a lawsuit against theatre owners producing their own content (which i disagree with -- why the eff not??) and i wonder if we will see some similar lawsuits again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118067/discussion-between-spencer-and-releseabe).